manually adding keyframe to the tracker
I'm trying to do object tracking but at some frames the tracking is stop. I want to continue the tracking by manually adding keyframe and move the tracker the the desired position. How can I do this? I can't find a way to insert keyframe manually to the tracker.
Insert keyframe (I) is not working if I already do auto tracking the the current track.
Thanks

You simply grab the tracker and advance the movie frame then position the tracker in the new location, it will add its own keyframe

ok found the problem , it's a bug in 4.0.2.  I tested on old Blender 3 and i works. But right now it doesn't work for blender 4.0.2 i'm using. right now after apply auto track, the tracker can't be moved at all. I will try to download latest version and see it the bug still exists.

I tested it on 4.2 alpha. its good there

Seems bug on 4.0.2. Thanks I will try latest version

I'm still downloading 4.2 , btw I just tested on 4.1 stable release and the bug still there.
